# The bones in a model is affecting another model

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I made two models and both gave them bones. But one of the armatures is affecting the other armature. Is is because they both accidentally share the same pose library I gave em? If that's the case, i tried deleting the pose library, but it still appear in the animation screen. what do i do?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like both objects are parented to the same armature and/or are using the same armature object in the armature modifier. You will have to have a separate armature for each model. You should be able to simply select the proper armature in the armature modifier as well as in the relations section of the object tab of the properties window.